# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data’: File exists

Tags: linux, shell

This is a simple question, but it is not working. The following script (fol.sh):

```
if [ -d data]; 
then 
   echo "exists"
else
   mkdir data
fi
```

Return:

```
./MergeData.sh: 1: [: missing ]
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data’: File exists
```

Comment: do you have a **FILE** named `data`? Just because it's not a directory doesn't mean it can't exist as some OTHER type of file (actual file, socket, symlink, etc...).

Comment: Since when do arguments to a command not get separated by whitespace?

Comment: The point is that `[` is a (built-in) *command*, nearly equivalent to `test`, *not* a shell keyword. You're invoking the `[` command with two arguments: `"-d"` and `"data]"`. (The difference between `[` and `test` is that `[` requires a closing `]` argument.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [ -d data ]; 
            ^
```

There needs to be a space here. The spaces before and after the square brackets are required.

Comment: that's not everything. he needs `-a`.

Comment: Pretty sure that's everything.